UITextView - Cursor jumping up and down
I have a UITextView wrapped inside a UIViewRepresentable. Whenever I edit text inside the view which is binded to a swiftui with a string state variable, the cursor jumps up around 100px and then after like 30 milliseconds back down. (See image)
In the image the cursor is currently directly after "pr"

I have tried things like settings the content adjustment behavior:
textView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
or removing the content inset:
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
The only thing that removed this behavior was settings the isScrollEnabled or the textview to false, but that is obviously not an option because now you can't scroll.
Do you have any idea why that happens?
Here is a (not so minimal) example on how to reproduce the error:
Usage:
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var text = "Hello, World!"

    var body: some View {
        SourceEditor(text: $text)
            .showsLineNumbers(true)
            .textReplacements([])
    }
}

Definition:
struct EditorTextReplacement: Equatable {
    var replace: String
    var with: String
    var cursorMovement: EditorCursorMovement
}

enum EditorCursorMovement: Equatable {
    case stay
    case goback(Int)
    case goforth(Int)

    var amount: Int? {
        switch self {
        case .stay:
            return nil
        case .goback(let amount), .goforth(let amount):
            return amount
        }
    }
}

struct EditorTheme {
    var lineNumberSelected: UIColor
    var lineNumber: UIColor
    var textColor: UIColor
    var backgroundColor: UIColor
    var selectionColor: UIColor
    var gutterWidth: CGFloat
}

extension EditorTheme {
    static let defaultLight = EditorTheme(
        lineNumberSelected: UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.78, blue: 0.80, alpha: 1.0),
        lineNumber: UIColor(red: 0.55, green: 0.56, blue: 0.57, alpha: 1.0),
        textColor: .black,
        backgroundColor: .white,
        selectionColor: UIColor(red: 0.75, green: 0.82, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.0),
        gutterWidth: 50
    )

    static let defaultDark = EditorTheme(
        lineNumberSelected: UIColor(red: 0.47, green: 0.50, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1.0),
        lineNumber: UIColor(red: 0.60, green: 0.60, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0),
        textColor: .white,
        backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 0.16, green: 0.17, blue: 0.18, alpha: 1.0),
        selectionColor: UIColor(red: 0.32, green: 0.37, blue: 0.43, alpha: 1.0),
        gutterWidth: 50
    )
}

struct SourceEditor: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    private var showLineNumbers: Bool = true
    private var editorFont: UIFont = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
    private var textReplacements: [EditorTextReplacement] = []

    private var editorThemeLight: EditorTheme = .defaultLight
    private var editorThemeDark: EditorTheme = .defaultDark

    init(text: Binding<String>) {
        self._text = text
    }

    var body: some View {
        SourceEditorView(
            text: $text,
            font: editorFont,
            showLineNumbers: showLineNumbers,
            textReplacements: textReplacements,
            theme: colorScheme == .light ? editorThemeLight : editorThemeDark
        )
    }

    func editorTheme(_ theme: EditorTheme, forScheme: ColorScheme? = nil) -> SourceEditor {
        var view = self
        if let forScheme {
            if forScheme == .light {
                view.editorThemeLight = theme
            } else {
                view.editorThemeDark = theme
            }
        } else {
            view.editorThemeLight = theme
            view.editorThemeDark = theme
        }
        return view
    }

    func editorFont(_ font: UIFont) -> SourceEditor {
        var view = self
        view.editorFont = font
        return view
    }

    func textReplacements(_ replacements: [EditorTextReplacement]) -> SourceEditor {
        var view = self
        view.textReplacements = replacements
        return view
    }

    func showsLineNumbers(_ show: Bool) -> SourceEditor {
        var view = self
        view.showLineNumbers = show
        return view
    }
}

struct SourceEditorView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var font: UIFont
    var showLineNumbers: Bool
    var textReplacements: [EditorTextReplacement
    var theme: EditorTheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SourceEditorClass {
        let textView = SourceEditorClass()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = font
        textView.textColor = theme.textColor
        textView.backgroundColor = theme.backgroundColor
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        textView.autocorrectionType = .no
        textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        textView.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        textView.textReplacements = textReplacements
        return textView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SourceEditorClass, context: Context) {
        if uiView.text != text {
            uiView.text = text
        }
        uiView.font = font
        uiView.updateTheme(theme)
        uiView.textReplacements = textReplacements
        context.coordinator.textDidChange = { newText in
            text = newText
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var textDidChange: ((String) -> ())?

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textDidChange?(textView.text)
        }
    }
}

class SourceEditorClass: UITextView {
    var textReplacements: [EditorTextReplacement] = []
    private var currentLines: [Int] = []
    private var theme: EditorTheme = .defaultLight

    func updateTheme(_ newTheme: EditorTheme) {
        self.theme = newTheme
        self.backgroundColor = theme.backgroundColor
        self.textColor = theme.textColor
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        drawLineNumbers()
    }

    private func drawLineNumbers() {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.saveGState()
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
        context.fill(bounds)

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .left

        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font ?? UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular),
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: theme.lineNumber
        ]

        let activeAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font ?? UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular),
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: theme.lineNumberSelected
        ]

        var lineNum = 1
        var lineRect = CGRect.zero
        let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.textStorage.length)
        var isWrapped = false

        layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: fullRange) { (rect, _, _, glyphRange, _) in
            let charRange: NSRange = self.layoutManager.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: glyphRange, actualCharacterRange: nil)
            let paraRange: NSRange? = (self.textStorage.string as NSString?)?.paragraphRange(for: charRange)
            let wrapped = charRange.location == paraRange?.location

            if wrapped {
                lineRect = CGRect(x: 8, y: rect.origin.y + self.textContainerInset.top, width: self.theme.gutterWidth, height: rect.height)
                let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? activeAttributes : attributes)
                attributedString.draw(in: lineRect)
                lineNum += 1
            }
            isWrapped = !wrapped
        }

        if self.textStorage.string.isEmpty {
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? activeAttributes : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 8, y: self.textContainerInset.top))
        }

        if self.textStorage.string.hasSuffix("\n") {
            let rect = lineRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: isWrapped ? (lineRect.height * 2) : lineRect.height)
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? activeAttributes : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(in: rect)
        }

        context.restoreGState()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainerInset.left = theme.gutterWidth
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func insertText(_ text: String) {
        var superDidInsert = false

        for replacement in textReplacements {
            if text == replacement.replace {
                super.insertText(replacement.with)

                switch replacement.cursorMovement {
                case .stay:
                    break
                case .goback(let int):
                    if let newPosition = self.position(from: self.beginningOfDocument, offset: self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: self.selectedTextRange!.start) - int) {
                        self.selectedTextRange = self.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
                    }
                case .goforth(let int):
                    if let newPosition = self.position(from: self.beginningOfDocument, offset: self.offset(from: self.beginningOfDocument, to: self.selectedTextRange!.start) + int) {
                        self.selectedTextRange = self.textRange(from: newPosition, to: newPosition)
                    }
                }

                superDidInsert = true
            }
        }

        if !superDidInsert {
            super.insertText(text)
        }
    }
}


Please show a [mre], some code that I can copy and paste into a new project and reproduce this behaviour.

one second, ill try

alright, this is the most minimal I could do.

I managed to solve it myself.
Step 1:
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textContainerInset.left = theme.gutterWidth
    textContainerInset.right = 0
    setNeedsDisplay()
}


Step 2:
func updateUIView(_ uiView: SourceEditorClass, context: Context) {
    let selectedRange = uiView.selectedRange  // Save the current cursor position
    let contentOffset = uiView.contentOffset  // Save the current scroll position

    if uiView.text != text {
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            uiView.text = text
            uiView.layoutIfNeeded()  // Ensure the layout updates
        }
    }

    uiView.font = font
    uiView.updateTheme(theme)
    uiView.textReplacements = textReplacements

    // Adjust scroll offset only if necessary
    if uiView.contentSize.height > uiView.bounds.height {
        uiView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
    }

    // Restore the cursor position if it changed
    uiView.selectedRange = selectedRange

    context.coordinator.textDidChange = { newText in
        text = newText
    }
}

Step 3:
override func setContentOffset(_ contentOffset: CGPoint, animated: Bool) {
    let previousOffset = self.contentOffset
    super.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: animated)

    // Prevent unnecessary scroll jumps
    if !animated && previousOffset != contentOffset {
        super.setContentOffset(previousOffset, animated: false)
    }
}

